Product name change
Is there a way or a program etc that can help to change products on 50k products in an easier way than Excel or do it one by one in Admin?
Thanks,

What is the source of updated names ?

You can directly change in the Database,
Save product name in the table 'catalog_product_entity_varchar'
-- for changing the product name you can change it in this table directly.

Please stop ignoring our posting guidelines: Do not use signature, taglines, greetings, thanks, or other chitchat.
